# Java - exclude array positions from a already declared array

Tags: java, arrays, position, tostring

So, the code below creates an int array with 100 positions, does some math and put every result value in the array positions, and finnaly shows all the values inside the array in a jLabel. The problem is: the last line will show all array values from 0 to 100, so even if a array position was not utilized, yet it'll be shown on the screen with a "zero" value, and I dont want it that way, I just want it to show the positions that really got a value. Im thinking on something to exclude the positions that I dont want to be shown so those wont go to the jLabel. Right now its going like this:

If i say that xconv is "13", with the code below, the number that I'll obtain and will be shown on jLabel will be "[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.......(until the hundredth position)".

I want it show like this:  If i say that xconv is "13", the number will be
"[1,0,1,1]"

Thanks!!!!

```
int []resto=new int[100];

    for( int cont=0;xconv!=0;++cont){

      resto[cont]=xconv%2;
      xconv=xconv/2;

    }
jLabel1.setText(Arrays.toString(resto));
```

Comment: [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has some methods whose names begin with `copy` that you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

instead of int[] build and Integer[] and use custom toString() to print only not null values.